# Create keyboard layout where capslock is control

Tags: fedora, keyboard-layout

I prefer to have capslock as control. On startup of my session I perform

```
setxkbmap -layout us -variant altgr-intl -option compose:menu,ctrl:nocaps
```

which does that for me. On every suspend this information is lost again. The script has to be run again which I bundled together with my locking script.

There are a couple corner cases where it is still reset. So I would like to make my favorite layout the system wide default such that I do not have to occasionally scream as my control key (which has “capslock” printed on it) does not work any more.

The system is Fedora 23.

Can I set the system wide default layout to the exact layout I have when I run with `setxkbmap` command? If now, how would I construct such a layout?

Comment: See my answer in:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402963/bind-capslock-to-control-on-ubuntu/704132#704132

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are using Fedora Workstation (or the GNOME desktop environment in another way), the easiest approach is to install the Tweak Tool (search in Software, or `sudo dnf install gnome-tweak-tool` from the command line).

In that applet, under `Typing` (weirdly not "Keyboard and Mouse"), there's a section called "Ctrl key position", with choices including

- **Swap Ctrl and Caps Lock**
- **Caps Lock as Ctrl**

For Version 3.26.4 of that applet, the above option is under "Keyboard and Mouse", then look for "Additional Layout Options".

Or (brought to us by the Department of Redundancy Department?), in the "Caps Lock key behavior" section, there's *also* an option for **Make Caps lock an additional Ctrl**.

Comment: Sorry, I do not use any desktop environment, I use plain Awesome.

Comment: Stuff like this is why we _have_ desktop environments, you know.:)

Answer (score -1):

It has moved, but still there F29:

**Swap CapsLock & Ctrl
 TweakTool| Keyboard&Mouse | AdditionalLayoutOptions | Ctrlposition | swap Ctrl&Caps Lock